# Modifying a N64 controller to connect to a switch

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches

I am trying to make a game, and I need to turn my N64 controller on and off from a micro controller (STM32F4). My microcontroller has an output pin that outputs approximately 5V, for testing reasons I have currently kept this pin high at 5V. To create this switch I cut the cord connected to my N64 controller (that connects the N64 to the controller) in the middle. I have 3 wires (red-3.3V, black-grd, white-data), which is information I got from online.

However if I disconnect the power (3.3V) for some reason the controller works only the joystick does not. The only way the controller completely stops from working is by disconnecting the ground. Therefore as shown in my circuit below. I connected the microcontroller 5V output to the base of the NPN. I then connected the ground output from my controller to the collector of the NPN, and the ground from the N64 to the emitter of the NPN transistor. I tried the transistor with an LED and it works, so I know my microcontroller and my wiring is not bad. However for some reason if I connect the controller with this setup and turn on the 5V from the microcontroller nothing happens (it remains disconnected). Anyone have any advice or other circuit designs to help me out please?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcbctR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is the ground of the microcontroller connected to the ground of N64?  You should have a 1K or so resistor in the base lead of the transistor.

Comment: Is the controller connected to a N64, or to your Microcontroller? If its to your micro controller, why not just disable your data input?

Comment: The controller is connected directly to my N64, the microcontroller is only used to control the transistor. I tried connecting it to each one of the wires and had no success (I even tried the data signal too). I tried connecting the grounds as well with no success. Sorry I forgot to add that in the drawing I have 1k resistor in the base lead of the transistor.

Comment: Disconnecting just the ground might not work. The data line is an open collector, so the controller might be powered via the data line bring driven low. And it's multi-directional. I think the best thing would be like an i2c bus switch ic, or a mechanical relay or two (data + Power)

Comment: What happens if you just tie the data line low?

Comment: If I connect the data line to the ground of my microcontroller, nothing happens. But if I connect the data line to the ground of the controller then the controller stops working. Which is what I want but how can I control this, would this be the same problem as before?